# Spring boot property read from application property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I have code where i need to pass table name in my Entity class:

```
@Table(name = "config_table_name", schema = "public")
```

Also, In the same way need to pass Sequence name too, like this:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "config_table_seq_id", sequenceName = "config_table_seq_id", allocationSize = 1)
```

I wanted to use like this from application property file:

```
@Table(name = "${config.table.name}", schema = "public")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "${config.table.sequence.name}", sequenceName = "${config.table.sequence.name}", allocationSize = 1)
```

Where my application.properties file is like this:

```
config.table.name=config_table_name
config.table.sequence.name=config_table_seq_id
```

I tried doing like this but it was not able to resolve the variable which i used.
Also, I tried finding out some more relevant code online but nothing concrete I did found out.

Hope the people in the community would help me on this. thank you

Comment: Why you want to pass such information as a property?

Comment: I have 2 azure pipeline define in dev environment where we are using 2 different tables having same schema backed with this code which i need to parameterize for 2 profile like dev1 and dev2.

Comment: Isn't it easier to take two different databases/schemas?

Comment: yes, i can make the another database as it is dev but I am more curious about how we can achieve the current scenarios with constraint.

Comment: Table and SequenceGenerator are not Spring annotations. Spring doesn't care about them. They are JPA annotations, read by Hibernate (or your alternative JPA engine). Those, not being part of Spring, don't parse and execute Spring EL expressions. So you won't find anything in Spring to do that. Instead, you need to read the JPA/Hibernate specifications/documentation to know if it's possible, and how, to externalize such values. I don't know if it is. If it is, it's probably done using some orm.xml file, but I've never done that. I wouldn't, either.

Comment: thank you @JBNizet I will read about the Hibernate how it can deal the external values.